# Spring MVC, @ModelAttribute, query parameters with "-"

Tags: spring-mvc

```java
@RequestMapping("/value")
public String getValue(@ModelAttribute RequestParams params) {
    return params.toString();
}
```

the request URL is:
http://127.0.0.1:8080/value?test-a=1

How can I get "test-a" in RequestParams?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to use `@RequestParam` annotation. See the documentation [here](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/bind/annotation/RequestParam.html).

Change your controller method argument to

```
public String getValue(@RequestParam Map<String,String> params){
 System.out.println(params); //will print the query params and their values
}
```

Now all the query parameters and their values will be stored as the key value pairs in the params map object.

Answer (score -1):

```
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestParam;

  @RequestMapping("/value")
  public String getValue(@ModelAttribute RequestParams params ,@RequestParam("test-a")String test ) {
   params.setTest(test);
        return test;
   }
```

Comment: @fengym i don't see your point , you can retrieve the String test and assign it  to a field in RequestParams